# Converting a image(png) to a string then encrypt the image 

Tags: java, image, encryption

I want to encrypt a image and then decrypt it. Is there any good references or tutorials or sample showing how to convert the image into a string then encrypt the string? Or there are other ways in encrypting the image? As I am a newbie to this and also I have went to search but there aren't any easy examples for me to understand and also to follow.

If I'm not wrong, i have to use the FileInputstream, and the ImageIO, but i do not know how does it fully works. Anyone can guide me? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An image is a binary file, so I don't think it makes much sense to convert to a String for the purpose of encryption. This would add quite a bit of overhead and complexity for no additional benefit.

You should probably just encrypt the binary file directly.

See:

- [How to encrypt/decrypt a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442264/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-a-file-in-java)

Comment: After encrypting the image, how will be the results like? Is it the image cannot be view? Or..?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "how do I perform encryption in Java", then have a look at some stuff I've written on [Java cryptography](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/), in partcular the section on [symmetric key encryption](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/symmetric.shtml). Essentially, you create some secret key, which can just be a string of random bytes generated with SecureRandom:

```
byte[] key = new byte[16];
(new SecureRandom()).nextBytes(key);
```

Then you construct a Cipher object and init it with the key, then pass it the data you need to encrypt:

```
public byte[] encryptData(byte[] key, byte[] data) {
  Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/PKCS5PADDING");
  byte[] initialCounter = new byte[16];
  c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,
    new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"),
    new IvParameterSpec(initialCounter));
  byte[] encryptedData = c.doFinal(plaintextData);
  return encryptedData;
}
```

There's nothing necessarily very special about encrypting an image-- it's just a bunch of bytes like anything else at the end of the day.

The main problem with cryptography is that there are various subtleties that you need to understand for it to be secure.

This link here may also help you out alot:

- [Using AES with Java Technology](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)

NB you wont need to convert it to a `String` more like a byte array-