# How can I password protect a file regardless of its extension in Java 8 ro Java 10

Tags: file, encryption, java-8, password-protection, java-10

I have tried doing this by encrypting individual files but I have a lot of data (~20GB) and hence it would take a lot of time. In my test it took 2.28 minutes to encrypt a single file of size 80MB.
Is there a quicker way to be able to password protect that would apply to any any file (text/binary/multimedia)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442264/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-a-file-in-java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962116/simplest-way-to-encrypt-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: Read them yet? Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673556/using-password-based-encryption-on-a-file-in-java

Comment: @Hearen Thanks for the comments. Sorry it took me some time to get back. I saw the posts above and I am able to do the same already but my concern is the time. Encrypting a file, especially multimedia could be very very slow. Which means I need to encrypt/decrypt every time and for 20GB+ this will take a lot of time. I was wondering if there is a quicker way than encrypting the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to hide the file from others, you can try to encrypt the **file path** instead of encrypting the **whole huge file**.

For the path you mentioned: `text/binary/multimedia`, you can try to encrypt it by a method as:

```
private static String getEncryptedPath(String filePath) {
    String[] tokens = filePath.split("/");
    List<String> tList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        tList.add(Hashing.md5().newHasher() // com.google.common.hash.Hashing;
                .putString(tokens[i] + filePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).hash().toString()
                .substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 5)); // to make it impossible to encrypt, add your custom secret here;
    }
    return String.join("/", tList);
}
```

and then it becomes an encrypted path as:

```
72b12/9cbb3/4a5f3
```

Once you know the real path `text/binary/multimedia`, any time you want to access the file, you can just use this method to get the *real file path* `72b12/9cbb3/4a5f3`.

Comment: Hey @Hearen Thanks for the solution. That approach is actually the closest to my requirements. Thanks a ton for the help. I will give it a try asap.